# What is the best thing to use to seperate images on sprite sheets?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite, sprite-sheet

Looking for a download a site or whatever that can be used to separate sprites off sheets. Please let me know what ideas you may have I have been using a download called sprite splitter but it no longer works for sprite sheets containing more than 10 images...Thanks!

should add ive been using spriters-resources to obtain my sprite sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pygame you can load one image with many sprites then use it to create many sub-surface and use it like seperated images. So you don't have to split one sheet in many files.

[subsurface()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface)

Of coure you can use pygame functions to save any sub-surface as seperated file.

[pygame.image.save()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save)

---

**EDIT:**

One image used to animation.

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))

# one image -> 7 subsurfaces

sheet = pygame.image.load('explosed-sprite.png').convert_alpha()

imgs = []

for x in range(7):
    imgs.append( sheet.subsurface((20*x,0,20,20)) )

current_img = 0

# clock - FPS

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# mainloop 

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # next image modulo 7
    current_img = ( current_img + 1 ) % 7 

    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    screen.blit( imgs[current_img], (150-10,150-10) )
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(12)

# save subsurfaces as separated images

for x in range(7):
    name = 'frame_' + str(x) + '.png'
    pygame.image.save( imgs[x], 'frame_' + str(x) + '.png' ) 
    print name, 'saved'

# the end
pygame.quit()
```

[image: explosed-sprite.png]

Save this image as `explosed-sprite.png` in the folder with python script.

Comment: wow okay I had no idea you could do that. what would an example code using that look like? if you just wanted to move the image around the screen.

Comment: See example. BTW: It is easer to use animations if you have one player/sprite/enemy (with all its images)  inside one class - than you can create many object - like many explosions.

Comment: In example I add code which save subsurfaces as separated images. Now you can create own `sprite splitter` :)

Comment: Okay so if I want to separate images on a sheet that's 1270 by 933 and has 60+ images on it(around 10 different animations), how would I tell pygame where and what images I want it to use? what info would I need to know?

Comment: You need `x, y, width, height` for every image on the sheet (x,y = top-left pixel of image). Then you can use `img = sheet.subsurface((x,y,width,height))` to get that part of sheet and you can treated this like separated image before. You can blit it on screen or save it in file.

Comment: so just to clarify cause im really slow obviously at pulling out the point. is there a good way to tell what x and y equal on the sheet? also the width and height is the width and height of each image? and how do you find that out or do you estimate? lastly when you blit the image what do the numbers mean? sorry for so many questions :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57241/discussion-between-python-pygames-help-me-and-furas).